# Perl: Accessing users and e-mails in a Domain or from Microsoft Outlook

Tags: database, perl, outlook, database-connection

I've recently taken over a script from someone who's left the company and it recently started failing. The code looks up a specific user and sends them an e-mail.

I've nailed the culprit line that fails to be (user and passwords is set to my personal account):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:IDM', $idm_user, $idm_passwd)
```

from this database the script selects the E-mail from a specified user login name.

I can't seem to find any documentation on the database IDM and was wondering if anyone knows of it?
Is it a built in Microsoft Exchange DB or Windows domain DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is connecting to an ODBC data source called IDM defined in the ODBC data source administrator in that system.

Comment: other lines are DBI->Connect('dbi:mysql:<databasename>') however I can connect to mysql and access the database. How is one to know what IDM is if it's using simply the ODBC interface. That could be anything?

Comment: you should look into the IDM data source in the windows host: open a cmd.exe and type odbcad32.exe; that should open the ODBC data source administrator and there you can see what data sources are defined for that host.

Comment: cool, didn't know about that program. It only listed the mysql driver... so I'm pretty stumped Ah well.

Comment: I thought it was just me not understanding ODBC but I guess he didn something messed up

Answer (score 0):

Ewww...

I have a feeling that the guy wrote his own database to do this particular task, and maintained that database.

I had to do something like this and used [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap-0.43/lib/Net/LDAP.pod) to read the user's email address from the Windows Active Directory, then used [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/SMTP.pm) to write the email. Of course, your Windows Active Directory must be configured to allow for LDAP access, and your Outlook email must be configured to allow for SMTP based mail.

You can try something like [Win32::AD::User](http://search.cpan.org/~prefect/Win32-AD-User-0.04/User.pm) to fetch the user's email address directly from Active Directory, but I have a feeling that you won't have read/write access to it.

If you can figure out how to fetch the user's information, you can try [Mail::Outlook](http://search.cpan.org/~barbie/Mail-Outlook-0.15/lib/Mail/Outlook.pm) to write the actual email.

I never used either of these modules. I guess I've been lucky that my Window sites allow LDAP access and SMTP.